# Use of private set property in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, getter-setter

Can somebody explain the use of `private` access modifier with `set` property and default with `get` property in C# getter and setter methods? I am pretty new to the C# programming language.

Sample code:

```
public Status
{
    get { return my_status; }
    private set
    {
            if (value != my_status)
            {
                //something here
                my_status=value;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a case of reading the specs and/or doing some tutorials online. Asking here for a basic keyword meaning question is a little over the top.

Comment: This property is missing a type...

Comment: Please check the answer for this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313184/private-set-in-c-sharp-having-trouble-wrapping-my-brain-around-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313184/private-set-in-c-sharp-having-trouble-wrapping-my-brain-around-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify any access modifier for the `get`/`set` the property access modifier will be used. You can specify a more restrictive access modifier for `get` or `set`.

In your example, since `Status` is `public` but has a private `set`, the property will be readable from anywhere but assignable only from within the declaring class.

Answer (score 1):

private set is used when we want to **restrict member property initialization to its own class only not from outside of that class**